# How do I access views from a different project using thymeleaf

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

The project I'm working with is using Thymeleaf with programitic (java) configuration.

Currently, all views are contained in the webapp/WEB_INF/views folder and accessed with the following code in WebMvcConfig.java:

```
@Bean
public TemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    TemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix(VIEWS);
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
    templateResolver.setOrder(1);
    return templateResolver;
}
```

This works fine and the next step is to separate a module into a different project.

So far this has presented many challenges, the most prevalent being how do I access a new group of views in a different project with Thymeleaf's configuration?

I have updated projectB's pom & org.eclipse.wst.common.component files to so all projects build without a problem.

I have considered doing something like adding a second Template Resolver with a lower priority like:

```
 @Bean
public TemplateResolver secondTemplateResolver() {
    TemplateResolver secondTemplateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    secondTemplateResolver.setPrefix(VIEWS);
    secondTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    secondTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    secondTemplateResolver.setCacheable(false);
    secondTemplateResolver.setOrder(2);
    return secondTemplateResolver;
}
```

So far no success.  I have a feeling this may simpler than I am making it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean by a "group of views" , views inside a folder?

Comment: Yes, exactly. A group inside a folder.  To update: As a solution, I ended up separating the two projects, each with their respective webapp/.../views folders and will use a single sign on solution to access each project when requested.

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as this

```
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("folder1/helloWorld");
return model;
```

If you want to "switch to other project" :

```
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("folder2/helloWorld");
return model;
```